# enumerate environment starting on last item number and step down up to the first

Tags: enumerate, counters, enumitem, paralist

I would like to produce an enumerated list of items that starts on the last number and stepping down until the counter is 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item 1st item
 \item 2nd item
 \item 3rd item
 \item last item
\end{enumerate}
```

The desired output would be:

4- 1st item,

3- 2nd item,

2- 3rd item,

1- last item.

i.e. starting on 4 (total items on list) and decreasing counter until 1. That's because it is a list of tasks, most recent on first position but with the number of the last task carried out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See https://ctan.org/pkg/etaremune

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. It did the job. Thanks. I lost the ability to emphasize the item number (I'm using `paralist`), but no problem.